# Can we use 'was' instead of 'had been' keeping meaning?

Tags: present-perfect, time

Here is two sentences:

```
By 100 AD, the Roman Empire had been defeated.
By 100 AD, the Roman Empire was defeated.
```

Is 2nd one going to keep meaning of the 1st one?

Comment: Because of the *specific* verb here *(**defeated**)*, there's no real possibility of a significant difference in meaning. But consider  1: *By the age of 20, John had been married to both Jane and Joan,* and 2: *By the age of 20, John was married to both Jane and Joan.* With the verb ***married*** (referencing a potentially *repeatable* act / state), there's a clear distinction - in #1 we can reasonably assume John divorced his first wife Jane, then married Joan. But #2 unambiguously asserts that John is a bigamist (he's married to both women ***at the same time***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers great comment, thanks!

Comment: *We have been noticing this trend after a fresh install* is syntactically "valid", but it's not very idiomatic (smacks a bit of "Indian English", which you probably want to avoid). And *We was noticing this trend...* is simply ungrammatical. You might perhaps use *We **have** noticed this trend...* if it's somehow particularly relevant to the context that you *repeatedly* noticed (and/or are *continuing* to notice, right up to time of speaking) the trend, but usually it would just be Simple Past *We noticed this trend...*

Answer (score -1):

I prefer 'had been'. I also think that is the correct usage. (It's the past perfect continuous form). It indicates that something had been happening, up until the time you indicate. I think it also indicates that you're about to say something else,which would make this statement an introductory phrase. i.e. .. had been defeated, when .... took control, (or some such).

Comment: Nah. It's just Past Perfect. Past Perfect *Continuous* would be something like *...the Roman Empire had been **ruling** much of Europe for over a century*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Should we say it is the Past Perfect in its **passive voice**?

Comment: @SunnySideDown: No you shouldn't! ***Passive voice*** is where a specified ***object*** is "acted upon, affected by" a specified ***verb***, but where the actual ***subject*** of that verb is unspecified *(Europe **had been enslaved** for over a century).* Strictly speaking it's still "passive" voice if the "agent" (as opposed to the "patient" - ***Europe*** there) *is* specified, but not as in the actual syntactic "subject" of the verb, as in *Europe had been enslaved **by the Roman Empire** for over a century.* But that's not a typical textbook example.